# Force unmount volume in use by remote user

Tags: mount, dmg, afp

I store some sensitive data on encrypted disk images.  Sometimes for convenience I mount one of these disk image files (**.dmg**) over the LAN and occasionally forget to unmount it.

A problem arises where even if the client machine where it's mounted is put to sleep, the host still sees the disk image as being in use and will return the error:

```
The following disk images couldn't be opened
Reason: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

To gain access to the image I need to physically find which computer it's mounted on, wake it from sleep and eject the image.

How can I force unmount an image which is mounted by a network client?

Comment: Can you use `sudo umount -f <mountpoint>`?

Comment: the volume is not mounted on the host so there is no mountpoint

Comment: Need more information - where are the DMG files stored ? Are they on a network share or are they on a server or a network connected USB ? Is it a Windows or OS X system ?

Comment: @Danijel-JamesW - Both machines are running OS X.  The DMG is on a drive mounted on the host machine.

Comment: Can you check to see if the file is locked?  (*Get Info* on the .dmg)

Comment: The file is not locked.

Comment: Ok...back to the drawing board....

Comment: @Allan - if you have 2 macs on a LAN it's as simple as mounting one of them in Finder, double clicking a DMG to open it over the network.   Then on Host machine you will see you are unable to open the same image since it's in use by the client.

Comment: I am short one Mac this week. I was trying to replicate it.